# Anaconda Navigator is showing error while launching Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

I don't understand what the problem is at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you starting Jupyter? Which OS?

Comment: If you are using Linux opening a socket for listening can sometimes require sudo, depending on your distro.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.